# Change in master page using SharePoint Designer 2013 not reflecting in HTML

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I need to add a user control in master page in SharePoint designer 2013.
I have checked out the file and added the line below to it

```
<!--SPM:<%@Register TagPrefix="LogOut" TagName="LogOutUserControl" Src="~/_controltemplates/15/UC_LogOut/LogOut.ascx" %>-->
```

Now this should reflect in the master file also but after refreshing I can't see this control (comment) there in master page.

I also checked it in then also can't see this control. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You asked, and already got an answer, for this same question on the SP SE site: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/106160/change-not-reflecting-in-master-from-html-in-master-page-sharepoint-designer-20

Comment: answer there is not favorable. i need to first register and then to add. if i will add then it is giving register error

Comment: Am I missing something; why is your register tag wrapped in opening `<!--` and closing `-->` comment tags...?

Comment: Where are you looking for the register tag in the .master file?
Please note that it should appear on top, and not above the component as in the .html file.

Answer (score 0):

After checking-in the master page it needs to be published (I assume this is already the case since it is an existing one) an approved.

If you are on a multi web front end environment check that the change is propagated to all front ends accordingly.

Also note, as already mentioned by Stevangelista, that you just added a `<!-- comment -->` and not a control as you called it. You should revise your tag there... I assume you intended to do something like this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<%@Register TagPrefix="LogOut" TagName="LogOutUserControl"
            Src="~/_controltemplates/15/UC_LogOut/LogOut.ascx" %>
<html>
    <!-- head -->
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
        <LogOut:LogOutUserControl runat="server">
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that this is untested and that you should verify the code in is snippet!